# Alert me How to display word document in browser window?

Tags: javascript, document-library, word, script, open-with-explorer

We need to display a word **document inside the browser as part of our SharePoint application.** But when we tried to achieve this, it is always showing a popup with options like Open, Save and Save As. We don't want this popup and directly want to show the document in browser window itself (not in corresponding applications like MS Word ).

**We have a SharePoint application and document (Word) will be Stored at document library on SharePoint Server we want to display it in browser window on Client machine.** We are able to achieve this for PDF file but for Word (.doc or .docx) files, same code is showing a popup with options Open, Save, Save As.

Comment: Please write the code you are trying here so that the forum can help or correct you.

Answer (score 0):

1) In the SharePoint site collection, choose the Settings icon > Site Settings.

2) On the Site Settings page, under Site Collection Administration, choose Site Collection Features.

3) On the Features page, for the Open Documents in Client Applications by Default feature, choose Deactivate to disable the OpenInClient feature (documents will open in the browser).

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee837425.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

also within the document library. Goto settings for that doc lib -> Advanced Settings -> under "Opening Documents in the Browser" set to -> "Open in the browser" radio button and save.

for above to work you obviously need office web app installed on the server in the first place to display it in the browser, without this it will still ask to open save or save as.

2013

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855124(v=office.15)

2010

https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ee855124(v=office.14)